# Running dynamic script in DocumentDB from C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I need to be able to run a DocumentDB JavaScript script, specified in a string, from my C# code.

It seems to be quite straight forward to run a pre-defined stored procedure, but I can't find anything on running a script defined in the client-side.

Comment: Assuming it's written as a stored procedure, UDF, or trigger, you should be able to send the string to DocumentDB and it will execute inside DocumentDB. Please provide some code for a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, JS scripts (UDFs, SP, Triggers) should be prepared before execution in DocumentDB - precompilation and optimization should be done.

So as I see you should create that script as usual and run it, as there is no other way.